# alert does not process user input

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm working on conditional statements in js.  But ran into 2 problems with this script.
1) regardless of user input, the script doesn't process the else clause.
2) my alert method prints first the if alert(), then secondly an undefined alert().  Idk why this is.

```
<script>
function temperature (temp) 
{
var message="";
var temp = 70;
if(temp <= 69) {
    alert(message = "Turn on the heat.");
} else { 
    alert(message = "It is hot enough.");
            } 
}                                         
</script>
```

Then my body script is:

```
<script>
var myTemp=prompt("Please enter your current temperature."); //prompt is ok
//alert fails to process else clause and then prints an undefined alert()  
alert(temperature(myTemp));     
</script>
```

I have tried removing the alerts from the function itself.  That, however, kills my prompt.

PS I use Sublime 3 with jshint but this problem is out of jshint's jurisdiction, obv.

Please advise and thanks all.

Comment: `alert(message = "Turn on the heat.")` I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. variable = value would techincally be undefined, which is why you get undefined alert(). just return "Turn on the heat" and the `alert(temperature(myTemp));` should show your message. Or, do what @rac suggested.

Comment: because you are doing this inside the function `var temp = 70;` you are overwriting the passed temp

Comment: in your temperature() function, you only need to assign proper value to `message` and then `return message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using 2 alerts: one inside the another.. and also resetting your temperature value.

Use this:

```
function temperature (temp) 
{
  if(temp <= 69) {
     return "Turn on the heat.";
  } else { 
     return "It is hot enough.";
  } 
}
```

Comment: So, logically I don't need to initialize variables that are going to be input by user, right?

Comment: yes you don't. though it is a good practice to verify user's input. Because you cannot expect good inputs always. But you will learn that with time. for now it is good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) You are setting the variable `temp` to 70, so it overrides your input.

2) The `prompt()` function returns a string, which you are then passing into your temperature function where you are trying to compare it to integers.  Use `parseInt()`.

3) You are also nesting alerts since you put `temperature()` in an alert and your `temperature()` function itself also creates alerts.  Choose one or the other.

This is how I'd change it.

```
<script>
function temperature (temp){ 
    var message="";
    var temp = temp || 70;
    if(temp <= 69) {
        message = "Turn on the heat.");
    } else { 
        message = "It is hot enough.");
    } 
return message;
}                                         
</script>
```

and then:

```
...
alert(temperature(parseInt(myTemp)));
...
```